# Global Transactions in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I am trying to implement global transactions in microservices REST (with spring MVC). I have read that it can do it using the annotations @Transactional and @EnableTransactionManagement, however I have tested and it did not work with global transactions. I don know if I have done it wrong.

This [link](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) was the one that made me think that it was possible to do the global transactions with @Transactional.

In the test, I have created two tables in the data base (a and b).

Those are the codes in java of each service:

Service 1 (main):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/servicio")
public class a {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate objJdbcTemplate;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
@GetMapping("/1")
public Integer getValor(){
    int numero;
    int n=50;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Integer intRes1;
    Integer intRes2;
    numero = (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;


    intRes2 = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8081/servicio/2",numero,Integer.class);

    intRes1=objJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO A VALUES(" +numero + ")");

    return numero;
}
```

Service 2:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate objJdbcTemplate;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
@PostMapping("/2")
public Integer getValor(@RequestBody Integer intNum){
    try{
        Integer intRes;

        intRes=objJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO B VALUES(" +intNum + ")");
        return intRes;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Each service has the annotation @EnableTransactionManagement in its main (I have ommited the code in this question).

When the service 1's query failure, the second service that already has executed its query it does not do the rollback.

does someone know the reason?,
could Someone share me any link to read about it?,
someone knows if is neccesary to use JTA for this objective?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you call Service 2 via HTTP instead of directly calling the Java service method, are these services running in distinct processes at runtime?
The @Transactional annotation only affects the current process and has no impact on other processes (well.. probably unless you use JTA transaction manager and an application server, the referenced article describes JTA with embeddable (that is local process) transaction managers)

Comment: Also, if you can, avoid using XA (global) transactions:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: Hi. These services are running in distinct processes. Thanks Sergey I am going to read the information.

Comment: Hi. in the follows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5) I have released the question with more detail. Please read us and tell me yours opinions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Distributed Transactions XA in Spring and GlassFish 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5)

Comment: It question was answered in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5/46085159?noredirect=1#comment79173428_46085159)