# How to do Distributed Transactions XA in Spring and GlassFish 5?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, glassfish

I am trying to create a transaction comprising two REST web services, whose data source point to the same data base. The first service, named `1`, invokes another web service named `2` using Spring RestTemplate.

To implement the transaction I am using a JNDI connection pool, the MySql JDBC driver (version 5.1.35), JTA, XA, Spring and the GlassFish 5 AppServer.

Now, I have downloaded the maven dependencies in the Spring project, defined a configuration class using `JtaTransactionManager`, and configured the datasource and JTA properties in an `application.yml` file, like in the following code:

> Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Transacciones {

    @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(){ 
        return new JtaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

> application.yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jndi-name: jdbc/Prueba  
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  jta:
    enabled: true
```

I configured the JNDI datasource in GlassFish 5 defining a "JDBC Resource" named `jdbc/Prueba` in the "Connections pools" page using a `javax.sql.XADataSource`datasource named `pruebaXA`:

[image: GlassFish, Connections pools]

In the control layer of the web service `1`, the method calls the service `2` using the `RestTemplate` class of Spring Framework:

> Service 1 code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/servicio")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class a {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate objJdbcTemplate;


    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    @GetMapping("/1")
    public Integer getValor(){
        try{
            int numero;
            int n=50;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            Integer intRes1;
            Integer intRes2;
            numero = (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;

            intRes2 = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/servicio2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/servicio/2",numero,Integer.class);

            intRes1=objJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO A VALUES(" +numero + ")");

            return numero;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

> Service 2 code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/servicio")
public class a {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate objJdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    @PostMapping("/2")
    public Integer getValor(@RequestBody Integer intNum){
        try{
            Integer intRes;

            intRes=objJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO B VALUES(" + intNum + ")");
            return intRes;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If the two services work without errors, there is not problem. However, when the service `1` falls, the service `2` does not know about the error and does not do the rollback.

I do not know if I need to configure another feature/option in the GlassFish 5, or in the Spring program.

I have read that in Spring only needs a `JtaTransactionManager` bean and the framework performs all the work related to configure and use JTA-transactions.[Spring and JTA](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/)

> JTA
>
> Now, if you still need to use JTA, at least the choice is yours to
>   make. There are two common scenarios: using JTA in a heavyweight
>   application server (which has all the nasty disadvantages of being
>   tied to a JavaEE server), or using a standalone JTA implementation.
>   Spring provides support for JTA-based global transaction
>   implementations through a PlatformTransactionManager implementation
>   called JtaTransactionManager. If you use it on a JavaEE application
>   server, it will automatically find the correct
>   javax.transaction.UserTransaction reference from JNDI. Additionally,
>   it will attempt to find the container-specific
>   javax.transaction.TransactionManager reference in 9 different
>   application servers for more advanced use cases like transaction
>   suspension. Behind the scenes, Spring loads different
>   JtaTransactionManager subclasses to take advantage of specific, extra
>   features in different servers when available, for example:
>   WebLogicJtaTransactionManager, WebSphereUowTransactionManager and
>   OC4JJtaTransactionManager.
>
> So, if you’re inside a Java EE application server, and can’t escape,
>   but want to use Spring’s JTA support, then chances are good that you
>   can use the following namespace configuration support to factory a
>   JtaTransactionManager correctly (and automatically):
>
> Alternatively, you can register a
>   JtaTransactionManager bean instance as appropriate, with no
>   constructor arguments, like this:
>
> @Bean  public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(){
>
> ```
> return new JtaTransactionManager(); } Either way, the end result in a JavaEE application server is that you can now use JTA to manage
> ```
>
> your transactions in a unified manner thanks to Spring.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to do Distributed Transactions XA ?

If you invoke first a REST or web service and then another one, both operations will not be part of a transaction. To form a transaction, these operations must "start" a transaction or be "joined" to an existing one. To execute that transaction, your program must interact with a transaction monitor (TM) such as the proposed by [AT&T/Oracle Tuxedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuxedo_(software)) (released in the 80s), the [X/Open XA standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) (released in the 90s) and the [JTA-based systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API).

Note how the TM-based transaction works:

- **A transaction using XA datasources** is basically a program that invokes database operations on two different databases. The same program (e.g. invoking methods in one or more bean) starts the transaction, performs some operations on a database and performs other operations on another database. If one of the operation fails, the other operations are not performed or are rollbacked.
- **A transaction using XA datasources and JTA-enabled components** is basically a program that combines operations on one or more databases with other transaction-enabled operations. For instance, you can combine operations on a database with operations on a content repository or a network-based file system. You can define transactions that, when a database operation fails, does not perform or rollbacks operations on the file system. Non-transactional applications such as COBOL-based programs can be integrated in a transaction by defining operations and compensations in the transaction monitor.
- **A transaction integrating web-services** requires an special handling. For instance, there is [a proposal for webservice transactions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tranart/index.html) such as the *WS-Transaction* and *WS-Coordination* specification. There is a *coordinator* that works like the transaction monitor. The software must invoke the coordinator to start the transaction. Each participant in the transaction reports if each operation is successful or failed. The coordinator invokes the other operations or invokes the compensations according to the results.

Nowadays, there are some proposals for software architecture that do not rely on TM-based transactions. Designs based on [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) implement transactions using the [Sagas design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx). If you are interested on defining a transaction-like operation that invokes two REST services, you may consider to avoid the XA/JTA and program a Sagas.

> How to do Distributed Transactions XA in Spring and GlassFish 5?

You may check many tutorials in the Internet. For instance,

- a [tutorial](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html) that shows you three use cases: one updating two databases, one combining database operations and outgoing JMS-messages, and another one combining incoming JMS messages and database operations.
- a [video](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-tips-managing-distributed-transactions-with) describing how to manage distributed transactions in Spring with JTA
- and the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) from the Spring Framework.

> If the two services work without errors, there is not problem. However, when the service `1` falls, the service `2` does not know about the error and does not do the rollback.

That is the correct behavior. When you invoke a REST/webservice, the operations performed by that REST/webservice do not join to the transaction. If the invoking service fails, the invoked service will not notice it and will not rollback their operations in the database.

> I do not know if I need to configure another feature/option in GlassFish 5, or in the Spring program.

No. You only have to configure the XA-datasources. Spring will use your configuration class and annotations to join automatically into a transaction the operations performed by your application on these datasources. For instance, if you have a bean that invokes multiple methods that performs operations on one or more XA-datasources, these operations will join into a transaction.

However, when you invoke a method in REST/webservice in another application, the database operations performed by that REST/webservice will not join to the transaction.

Comment: I thought that transactions XA could be to shared among different programs (like a service or an application). Now I can see the transactions have to be in the same application (in context of my question). I have heared that WS-Coordination and WS-Transaction can be to used only for web services SOAP , but not for REST. Please you tell me if I am in a mistake. As I see, I have six options:1) SAGAS; 2)Try-Confirm/Cancel; 3) Atomikos; 4) WA-Transaction and y WS-Coordination. 5) BTP and 6) With a cordinator for web services (I want to ask you for the name of any cordinator) for java

Comment: You have two options if you want to use typical REST/webservices: (1) A Saga and (2) Try-Confirm/Cancel. -- Atomikos will not help you. It just another JTA implementation. -- WA-Transaction solutions are similar to (heavyweight) Workflow and BPM middleware. You must use a coordinator/orchestator that invokes the services, determine if they fails or not, and invoke other services or compensations accordingly. It is basically the same behavior of a Saga or a Try/Confirm-Cancel program. -- Nowadays, you may try Amazon Step Functions and Netflix Conductor.

Comment: Thanks Jaime. You has helped me very much. Your answers have been very clear. We are doing services orchestrationwith the ESB to IBM (but I believe that this does not do the difference to use transactions REST). I am going to work with Saga and with Try-Confirm/Cancel.

Answer (score 1):

rest web services (http based) are non-transactional by their nature (they are http based). you have made each method/operation transactional, but they do not share any state between the resources (rest operations). generally - you can have XA transactions over database or mesaging, not over http calls.

```
intRes2 = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/servicio2-1.0-
SNAPSHOT/servicio/2",numero,Integer.class);
```

Calling a remote web service is without any transaction context. If you need to maintains transaction between services, call the secord service as EJB (or as an injected managed bean)

Basically: using http-based rest services - forget any transactions between them. The protocol (HTTP) is not built for that.

The only thing I've seen transactional is SOAP with WS-RM extension (SOAP with reliable messaging)., however it is not very easy to setup (read: it can be nightmare to make it work when you don't know what are you doing) and not all WS frameworks support it.

When you really need reliable delivery between web services, there's a way. what is comonly used to achieve assured delivery is messaging with idempotent services (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) with store-and-forward pattern. In simple terms - service 1 stores a JMS message to a queue and there's a processor (MDB) which calls service 2. (yes, calling a remote web service it may happen that the service 2 will receive a message multiple times. Indempotency is a way how to deal with it.)

Comment: Hi gustos2, Thanks for your time. I am going to read the link of wikipedia about idempotent services. However for the exercise that I am doing  I need of transactional services. for this reason I want to know if you could help me to know how to do it with Glassfish. I do not know if for activate the manager transactional I need to do another configuration. because I have only configured the pool with JNDI and the global transactional no work.

Comment: Hi gusto2. I have updated the question, I hope that you can help me.Regards.

Comment: @J.Abel I will try to explain it simpler - when using **web (rest) services, forget any transactions** between them. Transaction context is supported between managed beans (EJB) and resources (JDBC, JMS). That's it. If you really must have XA, create a single web resource and call the secord service as EJB (or as injected dependency). If you really must have both as separate REST services, you can use "store and forward" pattern to ensure delivery (in that case you cannot have any rollback)

Comment: I have read about it in other forums and I have seen that transactions in web services are possible with  2-phase commit system, it can do without EJB. I have seen it in a lot of places. The question objetive is know how to implement 2PC in GlassFish and Spring, I want to do the transactions with a resource JDBC (like you said). More about this question has been answered here [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290917/what-is-the-most-accepted-transaction-strategy-for-microservices)

Comment: [more](https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/java-springs-tutorial-287/advantages-of-the-spring-framework-s-transaction-support-model-3944.html)

Comment: Using spring you can inject a bean using @Autowired or using XML (see 
[the tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html). The transaction would work out of box within a single method. (with **no web service** calls!! web services = no transaction).

Comment: @J.Abel: I see what can be misleading to you. In the link what you've provided, there are always considering transactions inside a bean. A bean method may be exposed as a web service (or may not, that is not important). But there is no transaction between a web service client and the web service itself. Using \@Autowired or injecting another bean, you should be getting working XA (really not through http post).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153641/discussion-between-gusto2-and-j-abel).

Comment: I agree with @gusto2. -- You can define a transaction comprising both `getValor()` operations. In such case, if one operation fails the other one will be not executed or will be rollbacked. -- If you define an operation invoking REST/webservices, a failure in the second one will not cause a rollback in the first -- You can create a program that, when the second fails, invokes a *compensation* to undo the first operation.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions across REST services are supported by http://www.atomikos.com

Cheers

Comment: Hi. I checked the Atomikos' products, there are four types:
1.- ExtremeTransactions Professional; 2.- ExtremeTransactions Basic; 3.- ExtremeTransactions Self-Support y 4.- TransactionsEssentials Open Source (Free). Do you know in what type are the Transactions across REST?.   In the [page](https://www.atomikos.com/Main/CompareSubscriptions?done_form=1) are the support included in each type product, but I can not see the Transactions across REST.

Comment: REST transactions are supported in the Professional formula.