# 2PC transactions (cross transactions) in GlassFish 5

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish

Does someone know if GlassFish 5 has support to use global transactions with 2PC (XA protocol)? but without install extra tools.

I have looked for information in the page of GlassFish "The Open Source Java EE Reference Implementation" where I downloaded the app server (and in other pages) but I have not had luck.

I try doing transactions in two microservices that insert two values in the data base. I have configured the GlassFish's JNDI with "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" and it looks like working, but when I check the data base only is added a value of one service. (the global transactions with 2PC does not work). I begin to think that GlassFish does not have support for 2PC.

I have read that it can do it with tomcat, but i need to add tools like atomikos, bitronix, etc. The idea is can do it with glassfish with out install nothing more.

Regards.

Comment: Glassfish supports XA transactions in all their previous versions (all the 2,  3 and 4 versions supports it). GF 5 is the new version for Java EE 8. I think it must work  --  Can you provide more information on the error ? Have you considered to report a bug to Glassfish ?

Comment: Hi Jaime, thanks for your early answer. In the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5) I provide more information of the problem.

Comment: As I understand, `/1` does not invoke `/2`. I do not see the transaction. -- How are you invoking the services ?  Where are you defining the transaction ?

Comment: Hi Jaime. The service /1 invokes the /2 in the code 'restTemplate.postForObject'. The transaction begin with  '@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)' above each method (they were named getValor). It look like easy for Spring Framework. Each service was deployed separately in the appservice GlassFish 5.

Comment: To join both operations in a transactions, the `getValor()` of the first class must invoke the `getValor()` of the second class in the same application in the same application server. If you perform a HTTP POST, the resulting database operations are not joined to the transaction. -- Your code does not include a transaction comprising `/1` and `/2`.

Comment: Hi Jaime. Yes, you have reason. I think that the transactions are administered by the transaction manager that has GlassFish (like 2pc transactions). these is activate when create the pool of connections of XA type.

Comment: No. -- If you have many connections from multiple users, you cannot join all the operations into a transaction. Each REST/webservice invocation of the same or a different user will have a different database connection. If you join all the operations in a transaction, an error of user X will cause a rollback of the operations of all the other users.

Comment: Abel, please check my answers. -- If you wanna create a JTA-transaction, you must invoke the methods but not the REST/webservices -- If you are interested on defining transactions comprising non-JTA operations or REST/webservices, you may consider to use the [Saga design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> Does someone know if GlassFish 5 has support to use global transactions with 2PC (XA protocol)? but without install extra tools.

Glassfish 5 supports transactions using XA datasources. You can create a program that executes transactions combining operations on multiple databases. For instance, you can create a transaction that performs operations into Oracle and IBM DB2 databases. If one of operations in the transaction fails, the other operations (in the same and in the other databases) will be not executed or rollbacked.

> I try doing transactions in two microservices that insert two values in the data base. I have configured the GlassFish's JNDI with "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" and it looks like working, but when I check the data base only is added a value of one service.

If your program invokes a REST/web service in a transaction, the operations performed by the other REST/webservice do not join to the transaction. An error in the program will not produce a rollback in the operations performed by the already invoked REST/webservice.