# Multiple transaction object from single transaction defination

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I need to manage the transactions for two database, and both are situated at different server.

I am just curios to know, among the below snippet which one is correct or more efficient. what about **SNIPPET 2**, is its correct ?

***can we have multiple transaction via single transaction definition?***

**SNIPPET 1: Multiple transaction definition**

```
    import com.awzpact.uam.domain.Userdetail;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
    import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
    import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

    /**
     *
     * @author jack
     */
    @Service
    public class NewPayrollService extends BaseN {
        final TransactionDefinition prayasTxnDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        final TransactionDefinition erpTxnDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();

    public void getSalarayData(final String yearMonth, final String regionId, final String circleId, final Userdetail loginUser){
     final String tableSuffix = yearMonth.substring(4, 6) + yearMonth.substring(0, 4);

     final TransactionStatus prayasTransaction = this.prayasTransactionManager.getTransaction(prayasTxnDefinition);
     final TransactionStatus erpTransaction = this.erpTransactionManager.getTransaction(erpTxnDefinition);

    }


    @Autowired
     DataSourceTransactionManager prayasTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
     DataSourceTransactionManager erpTransactionManager;
    }
```

**SNIPPET 2-Single transaction definition**

```
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.Userdetail;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

/**
 *
 * @author jack
 */
@Service
public class NewPayrollService {
    final TransactionDefinition transcationDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();

public void getSalarayData(final String yearMonth, final String regionId, final String circleId, final Userdetail loginUser){
 final String tableSuffix = yearMonth.substring(4, 6) + yearMonth.substring(0, 4);

 final TransactionStatus prayasTransaction = this.prayasTransactionManager.getTransaction(transcationDefinition);
 final TransactionStatus erpTransaction = this.erpTransactionManager.getTransaction(transcationDefinition);

}


@Autowired
 DataSourceTransactionManager prayasTransactionManager;

@Autowired
 DataSourceTransactionManager erpTransactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5

Comment: thanks, but the post didn't help me much